# Tomcat newly created JSP won't work

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I've got a problem with the tomcat when creating new .jsp files. I just got back to web development after 4 months of break and I have noticed that all of mine past developed .jsp files work just fine, however when i make a new .jsp file or EVEN copy-paste the working ones they will just not work with an Exception report message: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.ThreeParams_jsp"
I have re-started the tomcat server for a few times now, and still the very same problem occurs. 
I would appreciate any hints given to what could be causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be
1) There is no JAVA_HOME set in the env variables.
2) The server is installed in a folder where there is no write permission.

Please check these details.

Comment: It seems like the person's answer (i accepted in first place) was deleted for some reason. The problem indeed was the server being installed in C drive folder where there were no write permissions.

Comment: Adrian, it was deleted by some other who got better privileges. I don't know why my answer was deleted when I had spent hours to resolve your issue and then put my observation as a reply for your question. :(

Answer (score 0):

That problem causes when

1. JSP doesn't exists where it should be
2. Option suppress that JSP cann't be compiled

I think 1st is the main reason because almost web project has it's own build system(copy or pack wars).

It's maybe helpful to upload server.xml and explain your working environment(especially JSP).